# How to place Entry widgets in a frame on tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I've written some code in a frame and I need a couple entry boxes. This is a section of what I've written so far:

```
class HomePage(tkinter.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        frame = tkinter.Frame(self)
        label = tkinter.Label(self, text="Home Page")
        label.place(x=350, y=10)

        textLabel = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Start location: ")
        textLabel.place(x=150, y=100)
        e = tkinter.Entry(frame)
        e.place(x=250, y=100)
  frame.pack()
```

It is really trivial but when I run this the label and title show but the entry box doesn't and I can't work out why? Is it a problem when I try to place? Because .pack() works but then I can't control where I want to put it the way I like.

Comment: Class `HomePage` is not used and `frame` is undefined.  Also you need to specify the size of the frame large enough to see its children if you are using `place()` to layout its children.

Comment: The frame isn't visible, so the entry in the frame isn't visible.

Comment: Hi @acw1668 I haved used the HomePage, the code I have put is just a section. I used it in a container with other frames that do work, this is the only one that doesn't and the only difference is the entry boxes.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley how would I make it visible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I needed to specify the frame size, and for anyone else with the same problem if you're putting your frames in a container make sure the container doesn't squash the frame. Now my entry boxes are where I want them!